# How to understand "particularly if other things" in below sentence?

Tags: grammar

The terms on which the emerging undemocratic superpower invests in the outside world are of interest of all countries-particularly if other things, such as foreign policy, may be affected.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you get rid of 'such as foreign policy' part. It may help you understand the sentence better.

We are left with '*...particularly if other things may be affected*'

The part we temporary got rid of is an example **of the other things which may be affected* by the undemocratic countries' approaches in the world (of politics as I presume)*.

According to Collins Dictionary, you use particularly to indicate that what you are saying applies especially to one thing or situation.

Therefore, you can swap the word *particularly* with words such as *especially* or *specifically*.

The meaning then would be very similar.

I hope I managed to help you :)

As usually, knowledge of wider context is important to assess the meaning of this particular excerpt.